# How to fix the image to the top of the page even after scrolling in android?

Tags: android

I kept a **title image** to my **layout** and when I am scrolling the page **the top titlebar image is also scrolling upwards.** I want to keep that image fixed to top so that even after scrolling only the content should scroll and not the image. How to fix this problem? Please help me regarding this?

**My layout file:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget44"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         android:background="#FFFFFF"
         >
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout 
         android:id="@+id/topbar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/ins1"
         >
           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
           android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
           android:textSize="8pt"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           >
          </TextView>   

           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
           android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
           android:textSize="8pt"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           >
          </TextView> 

          </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your topbar *outside* of your `<ScrollView>`

```
<RelativeLayout 
         android:id="@+id/topbar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/ins1"
 >
```

Answer (score 1):

set your title outside of scrollview, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
        android:id="@+id/widget44"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         android:background="#FFFFFF">
     <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                 <!--Contents of title bar-->
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget44"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         android:background="#FFFFFF"
         >
     <!--Contents of scroll view--!>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

move the top bar layout to out of scroll view and keep those 2 inside a LinearLayout like following.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ins1" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8pt" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8pt" >
    </TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget44"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        //set the data for scrolling

    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```